# what is the best way to build downloadable store cards for mobile site?

Tags: php, mobile

I want to create a downloadable digital membership card(e.g card which we use at store after purchasing but these are physical cards. i am talking about digital cards) for my custom based php framework.

I have created one functionality where they have to login to access the virtual card but i want to create one functionality to download that card and save it on phone to use it as icon(like app icons). I can not use the bookmark functionality as i wanted to bipass the login and download it and save it as icon shortcut link.

what would be the best approach ?

Is the passbook for apple and passWallet for android is best approach? I am using custom php framework.

thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you use passbook for apple it wont be a good idea because the feature is officially only supported in iOS 6. However, a new pass wallet  Android app allows Passbook passes to be used on all  Android devices. So the best one to use is Passwallet for android

Comment: Thanks Refilwe. is it okay to use facebook's one login API?

Comment: The fast and convenient way for people to see your downloadable digital membership card.... so YES its okay